# Android Studio/JSON- Cannot resolve method "parseDouble"(java.lang.String)

Tags: android, json, api

I'm trying to get the temperature data from an API, and output it on my Android App.

I'm getting an errior saying "Cannot resolve method "parseDouble", what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is your "main" variable? You have main2 declared. Is it your misspelling?

Comment: Oh sorry! So my main2 is a JSON object that stores the information from the API, under the heading "main". Ill upload the other part of the code as well

Comment: Ok I see. But what exactly do you want to do by calling main.getDouble? main is a String and has no such method so basically this is the source of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
storeTemp = String.format("%.2f", main.getDouble("temp"))+ "°";
```

to this

```
storeTemp = String.format("%.2f", main2.getDouble("temp"))+ "°";
```

In your code main is String and main2 is JSONObject that you persumably want to parse.

Answer (score 0):

assign main as a double

```
  double main= Double.parseDouble(temp)
```